# Shiny App: Error in filter_impl: Result must have length 4090, not 0

Tags: r, filter, shiny, dplyr

Trying to run a shiny app, but keep getting the error: **Error in filter_impl: Result must have length 4090, not 0**

I've tried:

- debugging by removing individual filters to try isolate the issue.
- using `dplyr::filter` to force dplr's filter
- ensured all filters are in a reactive function
- checked whether it was an issue of sharing inputs between ui.R and server.r
- checked whether it is caused by a previous df transformation.

Spent about 3 hours trying to find the cause, with no success.

Can you please help?

**Server.R**

```
rm(list = ls())

library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(singer)
library(ggvis)
library(dplyr)


# Set Up DataFrames
data(package = "singer")
data(singer_locations)
sdf <- singer_locations %>% filter(year != 0) # filter out songs with missing years for simplicity
sdf %>% skim() %>% kable() # Check to see missing and incomplete values
sdf <- sdf %>% filter(complete.cases(.)) # filter out songs with missing observations for simplicity
sdf %>% skim() %>% kable() # Check to see if missing and incomplete values have been ignored

sdf <- sdf %>% select(
  track_id, title, song_id, release, artist_id, artist_name, year, duration, 
  artist_hotttnesss, artist_familiarity, name, city, longitude, latitude
)

# add new columns with rounded data (for nicer graphs later)
sdf$latitude_rounded <- round(sdf$latitude, 0)
sdf$longitude_rounded <- round(sdf$longitude, 0)
sdf$duration_rounded <- round(sdf$duration, 0)


# Add song_popularity & very_popular_song columns
pops <- sdf$artist_hotttnesss + sdf$artist_familiarity
sdf$artist_popularity <- round(pops, 0)
sdf$very_popular_song <- round(sdf$artist_popularity)
sdf$very_popular_song[sdf$very_popular_song < 1] <- "No"
sdf$very_popular_song[sdf$very_popular_song >= 1] <- "Yes"

# Select() relevant variables so they can be passed into server below (without having to use df[,"VAR"])
songs_list <- sdf %>% select(
  track_id, title, song_id, release, artist_id, artist_name, year, duration_rounded, duration, 
  artist_hotttnesss, artist_familiarity, name, city, latitude_rounded, longitude_rounded, longitude,
  latitude, artist_popularity, very_popular_song
)

#axis_variables <- reactive({
axis_variables <- c(
  "Length of Song (Seconds)" = "duration_rounded",
  "Rating" = "artist_hotttnesss",
  "Rating" = "artist_familiarity",
  "Year" = "year",
  "Popularity Rating" = "artist_popularity"
)

################################### SHINY SERVER #########################################
function(input, output) {

  songs <- reactive({  # Create Reactive Filtering Component
    duration_s <- input$duration_s
    artist_hotttnesss_s <- input$artist_hotttnesss_s
    artist_familiarity_s <- input$artist_familiarity_s
    latitude_s <- input$latitude_s
    longitude_s <- input$longitude_s
    year_s <- input$year_s
    artist_popularity_s <- input$artist_popularity_s


    # Apply filters
    songs_df <- songs_list %>%
      dplyr::filter(
        duration_rounded >= duration_s,
        artist_hotttnesss >= artist_hotttnesss_s,
        artist_familiarity >= artist_familiarity_s,
        latitude_rounded >= latitude_s,
        longitude_rounded >= longitude_s,
        year >= year_s,
        artist_popularity >= artist_popularity_s
      ) %>%
      arrange(duration_rounded)

    # filter by city option
    if (input$city_in != "All") {
      city_in_temp <- paste0("%", input$city_in, "%")
      songs_df <- songs_df %>% dplyr::filter(songs_df$city %like% city_in_temp)
    }

    # filter by artist_name option 
    if (input$artist_name_in != "" && !is.null(input$artist_name_in)) {
      artist_name_temp <- paste0("%", input$artist_name_in, "%")
      songs_df <- songs_df %>% dplyr::filter(songs_df$artist_name %like% artist_name_temp)
    }

      songs_df <- as.data.frame(songs_df)
      songs_df # return df

    })


  # search fuction
  song_search <- function(s) {
    if (is.null(s)) return(NULL)
    if (is.null(s$track_id)) return(NULL)

    # Isolate the given ID
    songs_df <- isolate(songs())
    temp_song <- songs_df[songs_df$track_id == s$track_id, ]

    paste0("<b>", temp_song$artist_name, "</b><br>",
           temp_song$year, "<br>",
           "popularity ", format(temp_song$artist_popularity, big.mark = ",", scientific = FALSE)
    )
  }

  # A reactive expression with the ggvis plot
  vis <- reactive({
    # setting variablex & variabley (input names are type str)
    variablex <- prop("x", as.symbol(input$variablex))    
    variabley <- prop("y", as.symbol(input$variabley))

    # Lables for axes
    xvar_name <- names(axis_variables)[axis_variables == input$variablex]
    yvar_name <- names(axis_variables)[axis_variables == input$variabley]

    songs %>%
      ggvis(x = variablex, y = variabley) %>%
      layer_points(size := 50, size.hover := 200,
                   fillOpacity := 0.2, fillOpacity.hover := 0.5,
                   stroke = ~artist_popularity, key := ~artist_name) %>%
      add_tooltip(song_search, "hover") %>%
      add_axis("x", title = xvar_name) %>%
      add_axis("y", title = yvar_name) %>%
      add_legend("stroke", title = "Very Popular", values = c("Yes", "No")) %>%
      scale_nominal("stroke", domain = c("Yes", "No"),
                    range = c("orange", "#aaa")) %>%
      set_options(width = 500, height = 500)
  })

  vis %>% bind_shiny("plot1")
  output$songs_selected <- renderText({ nrow(songs()) })

}
```

**Ui.R**

```
rm(list = ls())

library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(singer)
library(ggvis)
library(dplyr)


#axis_variables <- reactive({
axis_variables <- c(
    "Length of Song (Seconds)" = "duration_rounded",
    "Hotness Rating" = "artist_hotttnesss",
    "Familiarity Rating" = "artist_familiarity",
    "Year" = "year",
    "Popularity Rating" = "artist_popularity"
)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  shinythemes::themeSelector(),
  titlePanel("Artist & Song Data"),
  fluidRow(
    column(3,
           wellPanel(
             h4("Filter By"),
             # Slider Options for Data Exploration
             sliderInput("duration_s", "Minimum duration of song (seconds)", 10, 500, 100, step = 10),
             sliderInput("year_s", "Year released", 1900, 2018, value = c(1980, 2018)),
             sliderInput("artist_hotttnesss_s", "Ranking / 10 for popularity", 0, 2, 0, step = 0.1),
             sliderInput("artist_familiarity_s", "Ranking / 10 for familiarity", 0, 2, 0, step = 0.1),
             sliderInput("artist_popularity", "Ranking / 10 for familiarity", 0, 2, 0, step = 0.1),


             # Filter by custom input condition
             textInput("city_in", "Name of the city"),
             textInput("artist_name_in", "Artist's name contains (e.g Pink f)")
           ),
           wellPanel(
             selectInput("variablex", "X-axis", axis_variables, selected = "year"),
             selectInput("variabley", "Y-axis", axis_variables, selected = "duration_rounded")
           )
    ),

    column(9,
           ggvisOutput("plot1"),
           wellPanel(
             span("Degrees of Freedom",
                  textOutput("songs_selected")
             )
           )
    )
    )
```

Comment: Have you tried making this run outside the shiny context before porting it to shiny?

Comment: Given example code is too long. Is plotting, axis names part really necessary for debugging? Can you please reduce it only to essential part?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik - Yes I have, with no prevail.

Comment: @PoGibas - I'm unsure where the problem is, so I included it all.

Comment: You need to boil it down to the absolute minimal code needed to reproduce the error. Wrapping it in shiny is probably not needed.

Comment: You have a typo in UI: "artist_popularity" should be "artist_popularity_s", I think. Also, you do not seem to have selectors for "latitude_s" and "longitude_s" in the UI, but you try to access their values in the filtering function.

Comment: It would really help if you could make a reproducible example, however. At least, all required packages should be called at the beginning of the reprex using "library", and their number should be kept as small as possible (for exmple, you do not need  shinythemes::themeSelector() to run the code).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are filtering using data created by `input$XXX`. Try to put `req(input$XXX, req(input$YYY, ...)` at the beginning of your reactive element(s).

Also read [this tweet](https://twitter.com/hadleywickham/status/940021008764846080) about starting with `rm(list = ls())`.